# How is NULL value for a column with foreign key property mapped in ORM in python 2.7

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have following code in Python 2.7 using sqlalchemy as ORM :

```
   if j.request.component:
        comp_prod = (j.request.component.name, j.request.component.product.name)
   else:
        comp_prod = ('None', 'None')
```

But crashes with following error :

```
File "/remote/vtghome9/vgtools2/python2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/ChImE-1.1-py2.5.egg/kachori/extra/streams.py", line 4110
    comp_prod = (j.request.component.name, j.request.component.product.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I checked the "request" table, and for one row in this table -  "component" is NULL.
My question is if component entry is NULL , which means "i.request.component" should be None right ? Shouldn't it goto else part in that if condition ?

Comment: `null != none`... Also, looks like the variable in question is equal to `None`.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Thanks. think they are inter-changable in context of mysql and python. How do you suggest to check the existence if NULL is not equivalent to "false/None"?

Comment: There is no `null` in python! But anyways, `None` is a type, so just check if it equals `None`.

Comment: My guess is that it is not `j.request.component` that is `None`, but underlying `product`: `j.request.component.product`, which results in this error.